# Use iterator in class std::vector

Tags: c++, class, iterator, stdvector

I have a class

```
class node{
public:
    char name[5];
    int number
}
```

and I add some nodes to a vector named `node_list`

```
vector <node*> node_list;
```

I want to search through all the nodes and get the data in the `node_list`, how can I use the iterator to achieve this?

I wrote a wrong code, and I didn't know how to do it right.
Here's my code.

```
vector <node*>::iterator iter;
    for (i = 5; i > 0; i-- ) {
        for (iter = node_list.begin(); iter != node_list.end(); iter++) {
            cout<<iter->number;

        }
    }
```

I used Visual Studio to trace the `iter` after compiling, and it is the address of the memory, so is it like pointer? If I want to get `number` or `name[5]` in the nodes, how should I do?

Comment: Talk that outer for loop over with [your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Any time you have code and you're not sure about it, sit down and go through the logic. If it makes sense, it's probably good. If it doesn't make sense, talk though your options with your rubber duck and see which of the options do make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use range-based for loop:

```
for (auto &x : node_list) {
    cout << x->number;
}
```

Or:

```
for (auto iter = node_list.begin(); iter != node_list.end(); ++iter) {
    cout << (*iter)->number;
}
```

Note: `(*iter)` is typed of `node*`